# phpMyadmin can’t import file with error: open_basedir > enabled without access to the /tmp directory

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

After installing apache-mysql-php on Debian. I can't import `.sql` files to MySQL through phpMyAdmin. Error says:

> Uploaded file cannot be moved, because the server has open_basedir
>   enabled without access to the /tmp directory (for temporary files).

`open_basedir` is commented in both `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`
and safe_mode is OFF.

I set `777` permission to `/var/tmp` still get the error.

Comment: Have you restarted the webserver after making your changes? Also double check `phpinfo();` to make sure you're modifying the right php.ini.

Comment: Yes, i did. Still got the error.

Comment: Can you check [sys_get_temp_dir();](http://php.net/sys_get_temp_dir) and make sure the permissions on that location are OK?

Comment: returns /tmp folder. The permissions there are 777 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you say that `open_basedir` is commented out, what is the output of `phpinfo()`? There should be an `open_basedir` setting in there. And perhaps there is an `.htaccess` file—or another `php.ini` config—that is setting `open_basedir` somewhere.  That said, according to [the official phpMyAdmin docs](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html):

> Since version 2.2.4, phpMyAdmin supports servers with open_basedir
>   restrictions. However you need to create temporary directory and
>   configure it as $cfg['TempDir']. The uploaded files will be moved
>   there, and after execution of your SQL commands, removed.

So while you say that `open_basedir` is commented out—implying it is not being used—perhaps you should open up your phpMyAdmin config and set the [cfg_TempDir](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_TempDir) to point to `/var/tmp`.  The `config.php` file is located here in Ubuntu 12.04:

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Note that the error message refers to `/tmp/` but you are referring to `/var/tmp/`.

Additionally, [the issue seems to be covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772244#12772244) in the community wiki reference for PHP related error:

> The fix is normally to change the PHP configuration, the related
>   setting is called open_basedir.
>
> Sometimes the wrong file or directory names are used, the fix is then
>   to use the right ones.

So in your case you can perhaps adjust the `php.ini` to have this setting:

```
open_basedir "/var/tmp/:/tmp/:/"
```

And note that the only `php.ini` that matters in a case of web related issues like this is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.  The CLI `php.ini` located here `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` is strictly for CLI use and has nothing to do with the Apache PHP module.

Comment: Ok, this answer helped but what I actually had to do to correct this (Debian Jenny) was edit /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf and add there ":/tmp/" (without quotes) at the end of the "php_admin_value open_basedir" line

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved as follows:
I opened the file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf and found a tag  with parameters inside.
The last one was open_basedir

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/
```

I simply prepend */tmp/:* and that solved my problem

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /tmp/:/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/
```

of course I had to restart apache after that, but that was all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of the `php.ini` file. The problem is that the `open_basedir` is not set. You must set it in `php.ini` and also set the `upload_tmp_dir` to be under the `open_basedir`.

There is the same problem in Windows. Can be solved by setting i.e. `open_basedir = C:\Apache24\htdocs` (use your path to htdocs folder) and  `upload_tmp_dir = C:\Apache24\htdocs\tmp`.

Comment: In my case I had two otherwise identical systems (I thought) but one was installed later. During the transition, apparently, the default system upload_tmp_dir must have changed, because that value was not set in either system but failed on one and worked in the other. I changed the value in the failing machine to /tmp and *poof* it allows upload.

Answer (score 0):

An addendum to [Viter Rod's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274525/viter-rod) answer above is that you also have to grant full access to the tmp folder. So run:

> sudo chmod 777 tmp/

It should work after that.

Comment: The OP already says that the error persists even with 777 permissions.